# Correct way to structure an API

Tags: php, json, web-services

I have a small API that provides a mobile app with some JSON on request. This is the first time I have developed something like this but it is functioning well.

I would now like to validate and improve the structure of the API, since I've cobbled it together without much experience. My current implementation is as follows:

- in my public web directory I have a folder named 'API'
- in this folder I have two sub-directories, 'LiveScores' and 'YesterdaysScores'.
- each of these folders has an index.php file. This file queries my database and returns the results as JSON.
- my application accesses the specific path for the data it wants.(e.g. [www.blabla.com/api/LiveScores](http://www.blabla.com/api/LiveScores))

My first issue is that there is a lot of redundancy. For example, the two index.php files are almost identical, only with a different SQL WHERE clause. This seems suboptimal.

Beyond that, I would just like feedback of the 'proper' way to do all this.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using an API framework. A couple popular ones for PHP (that appear to be actively maintained/improved) include:

- [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/)
- [Tonic](http://peej.github.io/tonic/)
- [PhlyRestfully](https://github.com/weierophinney/PhlyRestfully) (for Zend Framework 2)
- [FRAPI](https://github.com/frapi/frapi)
- [epiphany](https://github.com/jmathai/epiphany)

Answer (score 0):

You can also look into using MongoDB (http://www.mongodb.org/), and build your API layer directly on top of it. If you want to use a web framework, there are plenty of choices. There are a large number of native drivers for your choosing (http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/).

Regardless, should be quick and easy to build and manage your particular API as you can store and run sophisticated queries on JSON documents from MongoDB. It's also a NoSQL database, and will be much better at scaling than the RDBMs that you're using right now; with the large number of mobile devices out there, you will need a way to scale out to the high concurrency of requests with low latency.

However, you will need to take the time to learn the Document Modeling approach and MongoDB. There are some free online training classes to learn the basics https://education.10gen.com/.